# Propagating gaussian wavepacket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gaussian-integral

I have a problem with evaluating the following gaussian integral in two different ways
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,t) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{\alpha^2 \hbar^2}{2} (k-k_0)^2} e^{(ikx - i\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)}\; dk
\end{equation}
The most common approach is to make the substitution $u=(k-k_0)$. The integral now becomes
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,t) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{\alpha^2 \hbar^2}{2} u^2} e^{(i(k_0+u)x - i\frac{\hbar (u^2 + 2uk_0 +k_0^2)}{2m}t)}\; du
\end{equation}
From this, we see that the linear term in $u$ has a time $(t)$ dependence. The result of this integral is a propagating wave part multiplied by a spreading gaussian:
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,t) = e^{(ik_0 x - i\frac{\hbar k_0 ^2}{2m}t)}  e^{-\frac{(x-\frac{\hbar k_0}{m}t)^2}{2(\alpha^2 \hbar^2 + i\frac{2\hbar t}{m})}}. 
\end{equation}

Note: I ignored an overall factor because my problem is with the functional form.
The problem is when I try to evaluate the integral without making the substitution. Then, there's no $t$ dependence in the linear term in $k$. I just took the formula for the gaussian integral with complex coefficients from the wiki page linked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory).
The integral now evaluates to
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,t) = e^{\frac{(\alpha^2 \hbar^2 k_0 + ix)^2}{-2(\alpha^2 \hbar^2 + \frac{i \hbar t}{m})}},
\end{equation}
which clearly has a different $t$ dependence. But the answer shouldn't depend on whether or not I make the substitution, and I can't see where I went wrong.